# Writting $a^x$ as a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $a^x$ where both $a$, $x$ are integers. Suppose $d = \log_2(x)$ the number of digits of x.

Is it possible to write this as a polynomial that contains $O(\log_2(x)) = O(d)$ number of terms? Or anything that's not exponential in $d$.

My intuition says this is impossible to do, but I don't understand why. I know how to do it for $O(x) = O(2^d)$ number of terms. I also know I could use Taylor series to do it in $O(\log_2(x)) = O(d)$ (or for any $O(d^k)$), but it won't give me an exact polynomial.